# Moving multiple rectangles around a scene after created with a button

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a scene, with a button; once pushed the button creates new rectangle object. The shape is draggable, however only the most recent one created can be dragged?

here is the code -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RectanglesCirclesDrawing extends Application
{
    Rectangle rect;
    Button button;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
         launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        button = new Button("press me to create a new rectangle!");

        // Creating a new rectangle
        button.setOnAction(e ->{
            rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.setHeight(200);
            rect.setWidth(400);
            root.getChildren().add(rect);
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{
            rect.setX(e.getX());
            rect.setY(e.getY());
        });


        root.getChildren().addAll(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Creating Shapes");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

How am i able to get round it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...  You are essentially calling

```
  root.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{
        rect.setX(e.getX());
        rect.setY(e.getY());
    });
```

so if you drag the root it will set rect x and y to e's x and y, so it's as if you are dragging a rectangle by clicking it, but you're really clicking your root, which means you can click anywhere in your stage, an it will drag the rectangle.

The issue is

```
button.setOnAction(e ->{
    rect = new Rectangle();
   ...
```

you are setting rect to a new Rectangle each time, and then you are trying to move only that rectangle.

What you will want to do is add `rect.setOnMouseDragged()........` at some point, before creating the next Rect object.

This should be the gist of it, good luck!

Comment: Further to that track the "Z" order and change rectangles if you get additional Clicks/Taps at the same location. I.e. cycle through the list.

Comment: @Lasagna, brill, got it! thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help.  Sometimes silly mistakes are hard to catch like that.